# Abort loading of AsyncTaskLoader on fragment detach

Tags: android, abort, asynctaskloader

how can I cancel a running AsyncTaskLoader?

The reference sais, there should be a cancelLoadInBackground() method to cancel a running task, but this method is not available in AsyncTaskLoader?!!

There are two other methods,cancelLoad() and stopLoading(), both do not work for me.

I need to abort the task, if someone switches from the current fragment to another one

Answer (score 0):

There is a v4 support library version of AsyncTaskLoader, but it does not include cancelLoadInBackground(). It does have cancelLoad(), but cancelLoad() doesn't have exactly the same functionality.

Comment: Yeah exactly, Im´using support v4 lib, forgot to mention that. Okay,and that means? I´m screwed?

Comment: Support v4 version 23 contains also the cancelLoadInBackground() method.